# Extracting xml tag and values with sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

I have some data in JSON format that I have converted to xml so I can pass it to my mssql sproc (hence the funny looking xml).

Now I am wanting to select a resultset that has 2 columns, one with the tag name (in this case 3018 or 3017) and the other column with the value, with a row for each node but there will be a dynamic number of nodes.

The reason for this unusual format is because most of my program uses JSON and this small part uses xml and I can do quite a clean conversion using the jsonconvert.deserializexmlnode method.

Psuedo code is below:

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated as I am struggling with this.

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
'<root>
    <3018>1</3018>
    <3017>2</3017>
</root>'

select T.N.value(valueoftag, 'int')
select T.N.value(tagname, int)
from @XML.nodes('/root') as T(N)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml fragment is not a valid XML. Tag names cannot start with a number or punctuation character.

Now if you were having an xml fragment like this

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML =
'<root>
    <_3018>1</_3018>
    <_3017>2</_3017>
</root>'
```

Then you can get names and values with a query

```sql
SELECT
    CAST(REPLACE(N.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(12)'), '_', '') AS INT) tagname,
    N.value('(.)[1]', 'INT') tagvalue 
 FROM @xml.nodes('/root/*') as T(N)
```

Output:

```
| TAGNAME | TAGVALUE |
----------------------
|    3018 |        1 |
|    3017 |        2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15013)** demo